# How to perform a database query on clicking a link using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with "Products" in it. And on the front end of the website I have a link next to each product that says "move to trash".

When someone click on this link `<a href="#">more to trash</a>` I want to move that particular product with id=2 to "trash" table. How to perform a query so it moves that particular product to "trash" table width product Id and Name?

Comment: Your question is too vague. What have you read about or implemented so far, and how did it work for you? Please experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ajax to run a php script which would execute the database query.

Here's how to trigger a php script using javascript and ajax: [How do I run PHP code when a user clicks on a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280767/how-do-i-run-php-code-when-a-user-clicks-on-a-link)

Answer (score 1):

Pass the variable via POST and recuperate it (sanitized of course) on that script. Something like:

`my_script.php?item_no=2&action=trash`

Really, there's nothing much to it in my opinion.