# how to run php code onclicking an image

Tags: php, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I run PHP code when a user clicks on a link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280767/how-do-i-run-php-code-when-a-user-clicks-on-a-link)

I have an image .

```
<image name="" src="">
```

I have a `php` code that needs to be run only after the image has been clicked.

```
<?php

$var = somthing;
if(condition)
{
    sql stmts;
}

?>
```

like that.

Both are in the same php page. PLease help me to sort out this problem.

Thanks..

Comment: Please learn at least elementary basics about technologies you are trying to use first. The keyword you missed here is "server side".

Comment: PHP is server side and javascript, if you want to run SQL after clicking an image you need an AJAX request

Comment: Wrap the image in a link and call the page with an additional GET parameter to decide whether or not to execute the statements.

Comment: Php runs in the server, javascript runs in the browser. You sound like you have a situation than requires the use of Ajax (In which a javascript event can request data from a php page)

Comment: Please before you start to programme in some environment, in your case in web, learn how things work first. You'll save nights of solving some basic questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can send a request with javascript. With jQuery that would look like this:

```
$.get("yourfile.php?function=imageClick", function(data){});
```

In your php somewhere at the top add:

```
if($_GET['function'] == 'imageClick'){
  // do your php stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't run PHP code on the client side.

You can do that through an AJAX call: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp