# Execute javascript for a particular get request in php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Suppose my domain name is www.example.com and I have a category, which contains many items. Example, Travel, Books, Education. Now, if I click on Travel the get request is `www.example.com/category/travel-areas`. Now, I want to execute a script when particularly that Travel is clicked from category, like `<script>alert("hi")</script>` it will be executed when I open `www.example.com/category/travel-areas`
This is my category.php file :-

```
<div class="content">

<?php tie_breadcrumbs() ?>

<?php
    $category_id = get_query_var('cat') ;
    $tie_cats_options = get_option( 'tie_cats_options' );

    if( !empty( $tie_cats_options[ $category_id ] ) )
        $cat_options = $tie_cats_options[ $category_id ];
?>

    <div class="page-head">

        <h1 class="page-title">
            <?php echo single_cat_title( '', false ) ?>
        </h1>

        <?php if( tie_get_option( 'category_rss' ) ): ?>
        <a class="rss-cat-icon ttip" title="<?php _eti( 'Feed Subscription' ); ?>" href="<?php echo get_category_feed_link($category_id) ?>"><i class="fa fa-rss"></i></a>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <div class="stripe-line"></div>

        <?php
        if( tie_get_option( 'category_desc' ) ):    
            $category_description = category_description();
            if ( ! empty( $category_description ) )
            echo '<div class="clear"></div><div class="archive-meta">' . $category_description . '</div>';
        endif;
        ?>
    </div>

    <?php get_template_part( 'framework/parts/slider-category' ); ?>

    <?php $loop_layout = ( !empty( $cat_options[ 'category_layout' ] ) ? $cat_options[ 'category_layout' ] :  tie_get_option( 'category_layout' ) );    ?>

    <?php get_template_part( 'loop' );  ?>

    <?php if ($wp_query->max_num_pages > 1) tie_pagenavi(); ?>

</div> <!-- .content -->
```

Comment: The question is unclear, but this might help: [How do I run PHP code when a user clicks on a link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280767/how-do-i-run-php-code-when-a-user-clicks-on-a-link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code there is no part, where exactly link is displayed. But i can suggest that you have list of links to different areas. For example :

```
<a href="#" class="travel-area" data-id="1"> Area title</a>
```

So i added some example to [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/48yy64eq/4/). As you can see, some part of JS code will be executed only when be passed if expression. You can change that expression, so add some additional check.