# How to run a seperate PHP file using a Button (Not a submit button inside a <form>)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have this `button` which is not a `submit` button, just a regualr button and **it is not inside a `<form>` tag.**

```
<button type="button" id="send" class="btn btn-outline-blue btn-sm">Send</button>
```

I need to execute a separate PHP file (`send.php`) when **I click on the `send` button**

I know how to do this if the `button` is a `type="submit"` and is inside a `<form>`

But in this kind of a situation, I can't think of how to do it. Please HELP...

Comment: Do you want to send some kind of data to `send.php` or is it just an empty GET request? Do you want to display new page? It's unclear.

Comment: You can use ajax for you're problem
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1280767/how-do-i-run-php-code-when-a-user-clicks-on-a-link

Comment: @Walk: Yes I need to send data...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use a button. Use a regular link. [Use CSS to make it look however you like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710089/how-do-i-make-an-html-link-look-like-a-button).

Alternatively, make it a submit button and put it inside a form. The form doesn't need anything else in it. You can [style](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) the form to be `display: inline` if you like.

Alternatively, [add a click event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) with JavaScript which assigns a new value to [`location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location).

Alternatively, add a click event handler with JavaScript which uses the [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) object or the [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) object to make an HTTP request without leaving the page.

Comment: Can you please simplify your answer?

Comment: @user8696864 — If you want the simple version, ignore everything except the first line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ajax to call the php class on button click event

Comment: You can take help from this link https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_ajax

Comment: The example you have given, `it is for a text file. Does it work with php files too?` **with the same syntax as in the w3school example?**

Comment: Yes u can add script in your HTML file and then call the ajax and pass php file name as url

Comment: I can't understand what you are telling Sir. Can you please explain by giving an example?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it:

with some research I ended up writing this `javascript` code which use `ajax`

Here it's my `HTML`

```
<div class="md-form">
    <i class="fa fa-user prefix grey-text"></i>
    <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject" class="form-control ">
    <label for="form-name">subject</label>
</div>

<div class="md-form">
    <i class="fa fa-envelope prefix grey-text"></i>
    <input type="text" name="to" id="to" class="form-control ">
    <label for="form-email">Your email</label>
</div>

<div class="md-form">
    <i class="fa fa-tag prefix grey-text"></i>
    <input type="text"  name="message" id="message" class="form-control">
    <label for="form-Subject">Message</label>
</div>
```

Here's my `PHP` file

```
<?php
    $mailto=$_POST['to'];
    $mailSub=$_POST['subject'];
    $mailMSG=$_POST['message'];
    require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail ->IsSmtp();
    $mail ->SMTPDebug=0;
    $mail ->SMTPAuth=true;
    $mail ->SMTPSecure='tls';
    $mail ->Host='smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail ->Port= 587; //465; //or 587
    $mail ->IsHTML(true);
    $mail ->Username="myemail";
    $mail ->Password="password";
    $mail ->SetFrom("email");
    $mail ->Subject=$mailSub;
    $mail ->Body=$mailMSG;
    $mail ->AddAddress($mailto);

    if(!$mail ->Send() || !isset($mailto) || trim($mailto)=='' || !isset($mailSub) || trim($mailSub)=='' || !isset($mailMSG) || trim($mailMSG)=='' ){       
                echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("Mail not Sent!!!!")';
        echo '</script>';
    }else{
        echo '<script language="javascript">';
        echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
        echo '</script>';           
    }
?>
```

This is my`javascript` in `HTML` file...

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#send").click(function () {

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'SendEmail.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: {
                        to: $('#to').val(),
                        subject: $('#subject').val(),
                        message: $('#message').val()
                    }
                }).done(function (data) {
                    alert(JSON.stringify(data));                        
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Well, hope you can get understand about this. Thanks everyone helped :)